# Проблема с Task'ами созданными динамически в backroundWorker

Tags: c#, list, task, backgroundworker

Регулярно встречаю проблему. Создаю BackgroundWorker. В нем инициализирую List. В цикле выдаю таскам задачи. Во втором цикле запускаю эти таски.
задача в таске - это выполнение некоторого запроса(библиотека xNet). Запрос один и тот же, но с разными параметрами.

Если я запускаю синхронно сам запрос - все ок.

Но когда запускаю через таски - создается N-ое кол-во **одинаковых** запросов(смотрел через httpAnalyzer).

Студия решила повиснуть, так что пример кода примерный(извиняюсь)

```
private void bgw_Tasker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        List<Task<List<string>>> Tasks = new List<Task<List<string>>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 18; i++)
        {
            Tasks.Add(new Task<List<string>>(() => ParseCategory((i+1).ToString())));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 18; i++)
        {
            //Tasks[i].Start();
        }
        int curProcentage = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            foreach(Task<List<string>> task in Tasks)
            {
                if (task.IsCompleted)
                {
                    curProcentage++;
                    bgw_Tasker.ReportProgress(curProcentage, task.Result);
                    task.Dispose();
                    Tasks.Remove(task);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Вот функция которую сую в таски.

```
    public List<string> ParseCategory(string Category)
    {
        List<string> Owners = new List<string>();
        REQUESTS.GetOwnersFromProductsList Parser = new REQUESTS.GetOwnersFromProductsList();
        for (int subCategory = 1; subCategory < 15; subCategory++)
        {string subCat = "";
            if (subCategory < 10) { subCat = "0" + subCategory.ToString(); }else { subCat = subCategory.ToString(); }
            for (int page = 1; page < 50; page++)
            {
                 List<string> resp = Parser.GetFrom(page, Category, Category + subCat);
                 if (resp.Count == 0) { break; }
                Owners.AddRange(resp);
            }
        }
        return Owners;
    }
```

Comment: Подозреваю, что дело в захвате переменных лямбда-выражением, но недостаточно данных

Comment: Указал реальные функции. Еще какие-нибудь данные нужны?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте скопировать значение `i` в отдельную переменную:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 18; i++)
{
    string value = (i+1).ToString();
    Tasks.Add(new Task<List<string>>(() => ParseCategory(value)));
}
```

**Пояснение:** Когда переменная (`i` в данном случае) попадает в лямбда-выражение, компилятор создает [замыкание](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)) связанное с *самой переменной*, а не с ее значением.

В результате все объекты `Task` получают ссылку на одну и ту же переменную. В момент исполнения заданий значение переменной уже не изменяется, соответственно все выполнят один и тот же запрос.

Для того, чтобы избежать возникновения подобных ситуаций лучше не включать внешние переменные в лямбда выражения.

**Подробнее:**

- [Captured variable in a loop in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271440/captured-variable-in-a-loop-in-c-sharp) — в английской версии;
- [Closing over the loop variable considered harmful](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful/) — в блоге Эрика Липперта;
- [How to tell a lambda function to capture a copy instead of a reference in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451779/how-to-tell-a-lambda-function-to-capture-a-copy-instead-of-a-reference-in-c) — еще один похожий вопрос.

Comment: Это помогло! Огромное спасибо! Не могли бы вы объяснить, в чем собственно проблема? Думаю это не единичный случай, так что полезно знать причины...

Comment: @АлександрЛи Рад слышать! Сам не проверял, поэтому не был уверен, что дело именно в этом. Добавил пояснения и ссылки.

Comment: Уровень английского пока не позволяет разбираться в непонятных мне вещах. Прочел статью с вики. Сложно это для меня. Пока просто приму к сведению, что если возникает проблема с переменными, стоит попробовать переобъявить переменную внутри функции.
Огромное спасибо за помощь. Теперь буду знать куда идти в случае проблем)

Comment: @АлександрЛи если просто, то нужно отслеживать все переменные, которые входят в лямбда-выражение.

Comment: Как я и предполагал, переменная i захватывается лямбдой, а когда дела доходит до выполнения - в этой переменной уже другое значение.